# Userform Input Date Verification between IsDate and checking if the value is blank

Tags: excel, vba

When using `IsDate(date.Value) = False` from a userform input, does that include a blank value (such as `date.Value = ""`)? Would it be redundant to use the following:

```
If date.Value = "" Or IsDate(date.Value) = False Then
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Excel treats non-value cells (in the worksheets) and userform boxes as if it is a value, thus a blank, missing, or undefined value is NOT a date. `IsDate(date.Value)`, where `date.Value = ""`, returns FALSE. It is therefore redundant to ask `If date.Value = "" Or IsDate(date.Value) = False Then` because both values return FALSE every time when `date.Value = ""`. `If IsDate(date.Value) = False Then` and `If IsDate(date.Value) = True Then` are sufficient to check if any value, even if the value is nothing, is a date in userform input (and worksheet cells).